# How to pass php json array into a JavaScript function via onclick

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have to pass a PHP JSON array into a JavaScript function's on click event.

Before JSON encode PHP array structure:

```
Array
(
    [group_id] => 307378872724184
    [cir_id] => 221
)
```

After JSON encode array structure:

```
{"group_id":"307378872724184","cir_id":"221"}
```

The PHP JSON array looks like:

```
if(!empty($cirGrpArr))

   $jsonGrpArr = json_encode($cirGrpArr);
```

I need to pass the same into a javascript on click function like below:

```
<span onclick="Login(this,JSON.stringify('<?php echo $jsonGrpArr; ?>'))">click here</span>
```

The PHP JSON array is available in this page but how to pass it on click function so that i can iterate this JSON array to do some other stuff.

Comment: Why do people insist on writing JavaScript as java-script?! Nowhere, not in any documentation, or any half-decent tutorial, is it written that way. And yet it's a very common error here on SO.

Comment: A JSON string is in itself valid javascript.  When the string is printed it can be iterated as an array, or an object if it contains key/value pairs.

Comment: What is `$jsonGrpArr`? Don't show us PHP when you have a question about JavaScript. Show us the generated code that is sent to the browser.

Comment: What a convoluted way of assigning data to an event: make php print out html code with javascript inside it, make javascript dynamic by passing it json encoded php variables... all in one line. This will be a nightmare when the time for maintenance comes

Answer (score 1):

You can pass encoded object in function by this method.

### *.php

```
<a class="pointer" href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="return pass( event.target.dataset.param)" data-param="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode(array('key'=>value))) ?>">Click it</a>
```

### *.js

```
function pass(json_string='{}'){
    let data=JSON.parse(json_string);
    let value=data['key']??'';
    console.log('value',value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span onclick="Login(this,'<?php echo $jsonGrpArr; ?>')">click here</span>
```

and

```
function Login(e, jsonString){
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
}
```

Comment: but when i try to debug data via console.log(), its throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in console. any idea?

Comment: i am getting e as this object.. but when trying to debug data after parsing it is showing unexpected token error...

Comment: in `<?php echo $jsonGrpArr; ?>` I am assuming this a json string. If not then encode using `json_encode()` in php

Comment: ok then go step by step. first of all pass json and `console.log(jsonString)` to verify you are getting data as expected then move to next step and please print the actual error you see in browser console. copy and paste.

Comment: this is what i see when i debug via console... <span onclick="Login(this,'{"group_id":"307378872724184","cir_id":"221"}')"="">click here</span>.. actually there seems some issue at last of json  array when i did copy html from console. But while looking console the code was correct like Login(this,'{"group_id":"307378872724184","cir_id":"221"}')" and this "="" was not there... is it something causing issue???

Comment: your data is not being json encoded properly in php. Please verify your data

Comment: Bilal i hv updated the response i get when i debug in my question..seems it is getting correctly... i think the issue is where i try to assign it to on click function as json array is getting properly... or is it quotes issue, as json array is having double quotes around fields and the whole onclick is in double quotes.. any idea as i ahve no clue whats wrong with code...

Comment: try this `<span onclick='Login(this,<?php echo $jsonGrpArr; ?>)'>click here</span>`

Comment: yes that was the issue bilal... double quotes was causing issue and that was the reason why html code was scrambled at end... thanks a lot  man!